# xorg version in centos 5.4

Tags: linux, centos, xorg

Hi what is the release version of Xorg in CentOs 5.4?
can somebody do a 'Xorg -version' and paste the output here. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
[richardjh@centos ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
[richardjh@centos ~]$ sudo yum list xorg-x11-server-Xorg
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

...

Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Available Packages
xorg-x11-server-Xorg.i386              1.1.1-48.67.el5_4.1               updates
```

Hi, I see you have edited your question, so I will edit my answer.
The client is xorg-x11-apps-7.1-4.0.1.el5

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[DistroWatch says](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos) it's xorg-server 1.1.1.

Comment: sorry I should have been specific. I want to know Xorg client release version coming with CentOS 5.4, 
eg: ubuntu 9.1 comes with XOrg 11 release 7.5